# Uploadify HTTP error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, uploadify

I am using  uploadify for uploading some files on my ASP.NET MVC application.
As soon as I select a file after clicking the Upload button - I get the following error:

```
test - Copy.csv (0.15KB) - HTTP Error
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
    $(function () {
            $("#File").uploadify({
                'uploader': '/js/component/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
                'script': '/email/UploadFile',
                'cancelImg': '/js/component/uploadify/cancel.png',
                'fileExt': '*.csv',
                'fileDesc': '*.csv',
                'auto': true,
                'multi': false,           
                'buttonText': 'Upload'
            });
  });
```

And here is the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase fileData, FormCollection forms)
        {
            //some code here
            return Json(new { success = false, message = result.Message });
        }
```

A breakpoint inside the controller is not being hit.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Can you provide more details about the error itself?  Perhaps using Fiddler and/or Firebug can help with that...

Comment: There is nothing on firebug and fiddler. Fiddler shows that it hits the controller (along with the .csv file contents)

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before. For me it wasn't related to uploadify or my code. It was server related. Like, you when I selected any file, I had the http error. I fixed it by adding the following in my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Oh I just noticed that you're running a Windows server. Sorry about that. My problem was related to a Linux server running PHP. I know nothing about .Net but for the php server, an .htaccess file is a hidden file you put at the root of your website in order to overwrite some configurations. I don't know if you have the same for a windows server